# How many Objects are created when we add two Integer Objects

Tags: string, integer, wrapper, immutability

How many objects are created when we add two `IntegerObjects`:

```
public class IntegerObjects {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.print(new Integer(50) + new Integer(10));
  }
}
```

Is Integer, in fact all wrapper classes immutable like String?

Answer (score 1):

The + operation is being done on the values that the 2 Integer class objects hold. So the result would be stored in a new object or simply put a new memory space. If the above code is compiled and run the output is 60. This justifies that the + operation is being done on the values that the 2 Integer class objects hold. So only 1 new object is created.